# Advance to start of pointer array

Tags: c

I am trying to use an index to return back to the start of a pointer array, but am having a bit of difficulty. Here is what I have so far:

```
void free_x (char **strings, const int free_outer_array)
{
    int pointer_offset=0;
    while (*strings) { 
        pointer_offset ++;
        free (*strings); 
        *strings++ = NULL;
    }

    *strings = *(strings-pointer_offset); // this line?
    if (free_outer_array)
        free(strings);

}
```

After gathering the "offset" information on how far the pointer has travelled beyond its initial position, how do I "restore" the pointer to that exact position?

Comment: Wold it be simpler to store a copy of the original pointer? `char **orig_strings = strings`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’ve been adjusting `strings` (with `strings++`), so you mean to adjust `strings` back, rather than `*strings`:

```
strings = strings - pointer_offset;
```

But it’d be simpler to save the original value, or loop using a different variable.

```
void free_x (char **strings, const int free_outer_array)
{
    char **p = strings;

    while (*p) { 
        free(*p); 
        *p++ = NULL;
    }

    if (free_outer_array)
        free(strings);
}
```